# Using guava-libraries LoadingCache to cache java pojo

Tags: java, caching, guava

I am using guava-libraries LoadingCache to cache classes in my app.

Here is the class I have came up with.

```
public class MethodMetricsHandlerCache {

  private Object targetClass;
  private Method method;
  private Configuration config;

  private LoadingCache<String, MethodMetricsHandler> handlers = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
  .maximumSize(1000)
  .build(
      new CacheLoader<String, MethodMetricsHandler>() {
        public MethodMetricsHandler load(String identifier) {
          return createMethodMetricsHandler(identifier);
        }
      });


  private MethodMetricsHandler createMethodMetricsHandler(String identifier) {
  return new MethodMetricsHandler(targetClass, method, config);
 }

 public void setTargetClass(Object targetClass) {
  this.targetClass = targetClass;
 }

 public void setMethod(Method method) {
  this.method = method;
 }

 public void setConfig(Configuration config) {
  this.config = config;
 }

 public MethodMetricsHandler getHandler(String identifier) throws ExecutionException {
  return handlers.get(identifier);
 }
```

I am using this class as follows to cache the MethodMetricsHandler

```
...
private static MethodMetricsHandlerCache methodMetricsHandlerCache = new MethodMetricsHandlerCache();

...
MethodMetricsHandler handler = getMethodMetricsHandler(targetClass, method, config);

private MethodMetricsHandler getMethodMetricsHandler(Object targetClass, Method method, Configuration config) throws ExecutionException {
 String identifier = targetClass.getClass().getCanonicalName() + "." + method.getName();
 methodMetricsHandlerCache.setTargetClass(targetClass);
 methodMetricsHandlerCache.setMethod(method);
 methodMetricsHandlerCache.setConfig(config);
 return methodMetricsHandlerCache.getHandler(identifier);
}
```

My question:

Is this creating a cache of the MethodMetricHandler classes keyed on identifier (not used this before so just a sanity check).

Also is there a better approach? Given that I will have multiple instances (hundreds) of the same MethodMetricHandler for a given identifier if I do not cache?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does create a cache of MethodMetricsHandler objects. This approach generally is not bad however I might be able to say more if you described your use case because this solution is quite unusual. You've partially reinvented factory pattern.

Also think about some suggestions:

- It's very odd that you need to call 3 setters before running getHandler
- As "Configuration" is not in the key, you'll get the same object from cache for different configurations and the same targetClass and method
- Why targetClass is an `Object`. You may want to pass `Class<?>` instead.
- Are you planning to evict objects from cache?

Comment: I know very unique and odd case. The library basically checks the class meta data every time a class is invoked in the application. The cache will live for the life time of the application so there could be n invocations therefore n MethodMetricsHandler objects if I do not cache. The classes that go into an instance of MethodMetricsHandler can not be changed. However I see a problem with the setters as this will be running in a multi-thread enviroment. Any suggestions on a design change to make it thread safe?